# Position 2 vertical elements in the middle of the screen by using plain CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
  
  .top {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  }
  
  .bottom {
  border: 1px solid green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">Top Element</div>
  <div class="bottom">Bottom Element</div>
</div>
```

What i am missing to position those booth elements in the middle of the *.container* **next to each other** vertically with 20px gap only? Currently they booth are positioned in the center of every grid cell.
Sure, I can use simple wrapper  and replace grid-gap with some margins. But I would like to have as **less CSS and wrapper elements** as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the `align-self: end` & `align-self: start` given to *grid items*:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.top {
  align-self: end;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.bottom {
  align-self: start;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">Top Element</div>
  <div class="bottom">Bottom Element</div>
</div>
```

Or with the `align-content: center` given to the *grid container*:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  /*grid-gap: 20px;*/
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.top {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.bottom {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Element</div>
  <div class="top">Top Element</div>
  <div>Element</div>
  <div class="bottom">Bottom Element</div>
  <div>Element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. This works well. Is there way to do the same without targeting child elements? Like - whatever number of child's i will have, they always will stack vertically in the middle of the screen. I currently can imagine this only with wrapper. But mby there is some neat Grid trick.  That grid-gap is not so important. I can replace it with some margin or <splitter> thing. Auto-fit, minmax, auto-flow.. any?

Comment: Hmm... looks like *place-content: center;* do its job.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `grid-template-columns` if you want them **next to each other**

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, max-content);
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.top {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.bottom {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">Top Element</div>
  <div class="bottom">Bottom Element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: _next to each other vertically with 20px gap only_

Comment: @VXp well I understand that it should be on the same line :p

Comment: Don't think that's the case. :)

Comment: Tnx for reply. "vertically" i mean they will stack each on/under other. Probably you mean grid-template-row, but I tried this with no luck.

Comment: Hi. Tnx. Looks like i figured this out. *place-content: center;* works. What do you think about this? I know MS browsers has some issues with this shorthand, but i can replace it with align/justify.

Comment: @Dzintars you can try align-content:center in this case ;)

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out this way. Not sure is this the best solution, but will post it.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.top {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.bottom {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">Top Element</div>
  <div class="bottom">Bottom Element</div>
</div>
```

This way I can insert as many child elements as I want. I assume that MS browsers do not support *place-items* and *place-content* shorthand so you should use *align-content* and *justify-content* instead.